AWS ECS SpringBoot API with RDS PostgreSQL - all tables dissapear 3-4 minutes AFTER a succesful start up
MY ECS task connects over RDS's DB endpoint. I even ran my container locally to the RDS PostgreSQL DB and it worked without a problem.
As you can see all the tables are properly created an populated nad Spring Boot App starts fine.
enter image description here
Just about 3-4 minutes after all tables dissapear from Amazon RDS PostgreSQL DB.
enter image description here
ECS logs don't give any hint at all I only get sql error: 0, sqlstate: 42p01
Which only means that the tables are gone 
I also tried setting SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO=update so the App never deletes tables, nevertheless they seem to get deleted anyways. I've been trying to work around this for a whole day now, thanks in advance.
My guess is there is some sort of connection issue between ECS and RDS since my local container works fine with the RDS database.
By the way I have a load balancer connected to my ECS service. However I beleive that has nothing to do with it, but I turned on stickiness on the target group just in case, which also did nothing.

"My guess is there is some sort of connection issue between ECS and RDS since my local container works fine with the RDS database." That would not cause tables to actually get deleted from the DB server. A connection issue would not affect the tables at all. Also, you are correct that the load balancer is unrelated, although it would be interesting to see if this occurs when you only have 1 Spring Boot server in your cluster instead of however many you currently have behind the load balancer.  It could be related to multiple servers trying to update the tables at the same time.

I suggest increasing all the log levels in your Spring Boot application as high as you can, via logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE and redeploying, and then combing through the logs for any DB auto update thing. You might also try completely disabling SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO to see if that is the reason the tables are being deleted. The Hibernate auto-DDL thing is really not great for a production deployment, and you should probably be using something like Liquibase or Flyway instead.

I currently have a single spring boot server set up.

OK, then it isn't a concurrency issue. You can still increase the logging and look for anything suspicious in the trace logs. And you can try disabling the Hibernate DDL-AUTO to see if that solves it, and then research other DDL options if it does.

@MarkB I actually tested it once again on my local container + RDS and it behaves exactly the same . I went through the trace logs as well with no luck.
Properties (without db credentials):
LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK=TRACE
SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL=true
SPRING_JPA_SHOW-SQL=true
SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_JDBC_LOB_NON_CONTEXTUAL_CREATION=true
SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_CONNECTION-TIMEOUT=20000
SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUM-POOL-SIZE=5
SERVER_ERROR_INCLUDE-MESSAGE=always

On further reading, it sounds like you have the hibernate DDL-AUTO set to create-drop so when the old ECS task is stopped, after the new task has been flagged by ECS as healthy, it is deleting the records before it terminates. Even if you changed it from create-drop to update, you would have had to deploy twice to get rid of any old tasks configured with create-drop to stop seeing the create-drop behavior.
I would double verify that you have the configuration changed to update and perform a few complete deployments to verify the issue goes away.
And I would still recommend switching to Flyway or Liquibase for your DDL management in the future.

Thanks. Now I'm debugging it on my local docker engine. Went through the logs and I only see DROP statements at the beginning of the app. Not later on.
2024-07-12 12:52:26     drop table if exists public.student cascade
2024-07-12 12:52:26 2024-07-12 15:52:26.152  WARN 50 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2024-07-12 12:52:26 2024-07-12 15:52:26.152  WARN 50 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : table "student" does not exist, skipping
2024-07-12 12:52:26 Hibernate:

You still have it in create-drop mode if you are seeing DROP statements.

Yeah, thanks. I did remove SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO and tried re-running the container until all of the sudden it seemed to work as it should. Pretty odd.
